# I can't run pip2 or pip3 separately

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I have both python versions 2.7 and 3.6. I have created different environmental variables "python2" to run 2.7 on cmd and "python" runs 3.6. However I could not do the same with pip with variables pip3 and pip2. In fact when I go to the python 3 directory in scripts and run "pip" on cmd it runs pip for 3.6 version. But if I go to the python 2.7 directory in scripts and try to run pip.exe on cme I get an error "Failed to access Process".

Comment: Start using "virtual environment"! Like [this one](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) or [this one](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: yes, pyenv lets you nicely switch between as many installed Python versions as you like each with its own installed modules and only 'pip' is needed not pip3..